# connectiondidfinishloading not being called

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I've tried to search around for an answer but haven't found a solution that worked for me.

All I'm trying to do is set up my NSURLConnection correctly.  When I invoke doSomethingTwo(), I get printouts from didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData, but not didFailWithError or connectionDidFinishLoading.  Is there something else I need to do that I'm missing?

Here is my code:

```
- (void) doSomethingTwo: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem
{
    NSLog(@"The second menu was called");
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theholyroller.net/iphone/index.php"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
    NSLog(@"Received Response");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Received Data");
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed with error");
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Finished Loading");
    NSLog(@"%@", self.responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not capitalize the "L" in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.